# Manually place file at end of partition

Tags: windows, software-rec, file-transfer

I have an 80GB disk, which has a 50GB VM disk image on it. This image is currently in 220,000 fragments, and is killing my drive's performance (and preventing a defragmentation). I'd like to copy it off, and copy it back, this time manually placing it in the last 50GB of the partition. Since the file will never change size, this should prevent the issue I'm currently having.

Are there any special-purpose file copying tools which will allow me to do this?

EDIT: I'm sorely disappointed in Windows's file copy. I defragged my drive with 75% free space, and then defragged all free space. When I copied the VM back onto the hard drive, it ended up in 3,894 fragments. There's got to be a better way...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MyDefrag](http://www.mydefrag.com/) to do that using a script and the [MoveToEndOfDisk](http://www.mydefrag.com/FileActions-MoveToEndOfDisk.html) action. It's also excellent at defragmentation.

Comment: `"... try to find a gap above that file big enough to hold the file... If no gap is found then skip the file."` Unfortunately the file is bigger than half my hard drive, so this function won't work (it will never find a big enough gap). If only it were smart enough to move the rightmost bytes first.

Comment: I tried this, and it finished instantly without doing any work. I also tried to place it manually using `MakeGap(VolumeSize - 50.1GB, DoNotVacate)` and `Defragment()`, but that didn't help at all (my drive churned for a while without any noticable improvement). Do you think any other command might do the trick?

Comment: @zildjohn01: I'm afraid there's nothing else I can think of. You might try their forums to see if anyone there has any ideas.

Comment: Well, thanks anyway for the help. I guess I'll see if the guys over there come up with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Under dos-box,

```
Usage : fsutil file createnew <filename> <length>
Eg : fsutil file createnew drv:S-H.file 1000
```

to build a space-holder, then copy all files as usual.
Then remove the `S-H.file` for future use.

Maybe: Best turn off the alarm of "low space on disk warning".